# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'cache_dir must be a directory

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, wampserver

A Zend MVC existing project not able to run my windows 7 laptop(64 bit). I am using wamp server and my existing project folder is in www folder.

Every times I get below error on the index page (1st page):

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message
>   'cache_dir must be a directory' in
>   C:\wamp\bin\zend_framework\library\Zend\Cache.php on line 209

Answer (score 0):

In your project, I guess you have certainly something like this:

```
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core',
                             'File',
                             $frontendOptions,
                             $backendOptions);
```

Maybe in the bootstrap.

In the $backendOptions, you must have the directory where are the files cache.
In my project, I have a caches directory at the same level as application directory.
So, I defined cache options like this:

```
$backendOptions = array('cache_dir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../caches');
```

Hope it will help you.